# AWK function filter log

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ffmpeg, awk

I want to read a log and make some decisions depending on what is happening with my program. My script is based on `ffmpeg` and I am redirecting the `stdout` to make the log. Then I am reading the log to take decisions. My function is:

```
YT-PACTIONS()
{
tail -f $MSSLOGS/$project-$intnumber/$project-$intnumber-cache.log | awk '/speed/ { speed=$10 ; print speed ; }'
}
```

This is not working. It fills the var `speed` with the `$1` and not the `$10`. I tried `${10}` and didn't work either.

If I send the command in the shellscript it works:

```
tail -f $MSSLOGS/$project-$intnumber/$project-$intnumber-cache.log | awk '/speed/ { speed=$10 ; print speed ; }'
```

But I have a problem here too. It shows me the result:

```
speed=1.01
speed=1.01
speed=1.03
speed=1.02
speed=1.01
speed=1.04
```

But I want to see only the number in the following way:

```
1.01
1.04
1.03    
1.02
1.01
```

So I have two errors: the `$10` first and then to save only numbers in the variable.

Sample log:

```
  CloneNew PasteExpire in 23 h
frame=  279 fps=257 q=30.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.76 bitrate=N/A dup=111 drop=0 speed=5.3x    
frame=  344 fps=214 q=30.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.06 bitrate=N/A dup=137 drop=0 speed=4.39x    
frame=  419 fps=198 q=29.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.57 bitrate=N/A dup=167 drop=0 speed=4.06x 
frame=  526 fps=201 q=29.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.70 bitrate=N/A dup=210 drop=0 speed=4.09x
frame=  741 fps=116 q=28.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.04 bitrate=N/A dup=296 drop=0 speed=2.36x 
frame=  848 fps=123 q=32.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.13 bitrate=N/A dup=339 drop=0 speed=2.49x
frame= 1084 fps=147 q=31.0 size=N/A time=00:00:21.86 bitrate=N/A dup=433 drop=0 speed=2.97x
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the log that gets piped into `awk`? Do not post it as a comment. Edit your post to add this.

Comment: The first line has `speed= 5.3x` with a space after the `=`. Is it the real output or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this GNU awk script:

```
awk -v RS='[ \n]' -F'=' '/speed/{print $2+0}' file
```

The record separator `RS` and `FS` are set to match `key=value` string.

Then the string `speed` is match and its associated value printed. Note the `+0` to get rid of the `x` at the end of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a substring of the column you want using GNU `awk`'s `substr` function:

```
awk '/speed/ {print substr($10, 7)+0}' file
```

or

```
awk '/speed/ {print substr($10, 7, length($10)-7)}' file
```

The `substr` syntax is:

```
substr(string, start [, length ])
```

Both of the above commands are equivalent:

- In the first we add `0` to the substring to get rid of the `x` (in `awk` adding a number to a string that starts with a number keeps only the numerical part).
- In the second we select the length of the substring to be one character less than the `$10` length (it's `length($10)-7` and not `length($10)-1` because we started the slicing at the 7th character).

The output is:

```
5.3
4.39
4.06
4.09
2.36
2.49
2.97
```